# when to go for constructor injection and when to go for parameter injection in Spring

Tags: spring, inversion-of-control

I'm a fresher, I'm recently started learning Spring.In spring dependency injection,we
can inject a bean in 2 ways,one is through constructor and the other one is through 
setter method.My question is, for what situations constructor injection is better and
for what situations setter method injection is better. my focus only on where to use?
Give me an example if possible... waiting for your valuable reply..

Comment: [This](http://blog.springsource.com/2007/07/11/setter-injection-versus-constructor-injection-and-the-use-of-required/) will help you...:)

Comment: http://misko.hevery.com/2009/02/19/constructor-injection-vs-setter-injection/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a third way: Field injection.

You can directly apply the Annotation `@Resource`, `@Inject` or `@Autowire` at a (even private) field. This field even does not need to hava a getter or setter.

If you are building a Spring application, and there is no plan to use the classes in a not Spring application or a library, then the field injection is enough for 90% of the classes.
I prefer it, because it is less code.

*Of course if you use a constructor for mandatory references then there is no way to forget one of them when creating a new instance. But (and this is my point of view, that differs from Alef Arendsen in his 3 year old Spring 2.0 blog entry "[Setter injection versus constructor injection and the use of @Required"](http://blog.springsource.com/2007/07/11/setter-injection-versus-constructor-injection-and-the-use-of-required/)) you have a spring bean and not a simple class. And this bean is created by spring, not directly by you. So if you use  `@Resource`, `@Inject` or `@Autowire` for fields or setter spring checks them too and do not put the bean and the whole application in service if not all references can be satisfied.*

Comment: @denis.solonenk I use a Util that create mocks and inject them for all fields marked with `@Resource`, `@Inject`, `@Autowire` of an given object. -- This tool is designed for open source, unfortunately I did not have had found the time to publish it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say go for `constructor injection`.

In some cases go for `setter injection` if dependency is optional.

If you forced to use setter injection and use Spring, the use `@Required` to ask Spring to enforce it.

Apply common sense in all cases :)